# Delete certain text pattern in python

Tags: python, r, text-processing

I'm trying to get rid of a certain pattern of text in my .txt file, which looks something like:

---

```
mystring = '''

example deletion words
in the first block

First sentence to keep.

example deletion words
in the second block

Second sentence to keep.

example deletion words
in the third block

Third sentence to keep.

example deletion words
in the fourth block'''
```

---

My desired output would look like:

---

"First sentence to keep.

Second sentence to keep.

Third sentence to keep."

---

So what I'm trying to do is get rid of all text between the strings "example" and "block", including the strings themselves. Any idea how I would go about that in either R or Python?

---

Sorry for forgetting to include my attempt with regex and just asking out of the blue and thanks to the people who took the effort to answer regardless. My working solution using regex and re package in python:

```
import re

cleanedtext = re.sub('\nexample.*?block','',mystring, flags=re.DOTALL)

print(cleanedtext)
```

Comment: [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  The basic techniques of file read/write and string manipulation are documented quite well in many tutorials; we expect you to make a reasonable attempt to post here.

Comment: @Prune sorry for leaving my question like this, I thought I was gonna come right back with my question regarding my regex attempt, but I got lost in it for too long. Didn't just want to leave the blank question and can totally understand the downvotes for it.

Comment: Also see [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Include the result you got, and what you expected.

Comment: Yes, I know, again, I'm really sorry, I originally intended to edit the question right after I posted it, but I forgot. Won't happen again.

Comment: Should I delete it or leave it up?

Comment: Since you added a working solution, I suggest that you leave it up.  I rescinded my closure vote and switch the down-vote to up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In R, you can use `str_remove_all` from `stringr`

```
stringr::str_remove_all(string, "example.*block")
 #[1] " First sentence to keep.\nSecond sentence to keep.\nThird sentence to keep.\n"
```

which is shorthand for

```
stringr::str_replace_all(string, "example.*block", "")
```

**data**

```
string <- "example deletion words in the first block First sentence to keep.
           example deletion words in the second blockSecond sentence to keep.
           example deletion words in the third blockThird sentence to keep.
           example deletion words in the fourth block"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you already know the pattern ahead of time or does the pattern ever change? If not then you could read the text file, go line by line, split the sentence to easily manipulate, and then look for the pattern. For lines that don't have it, you can concatenate it to a new string. What I had below seemed to work:

```
f = open("mytext.txt", "r")
final = ""
for line in f:
    words = line.split(" ")
    if(words[0] == "example" or words[len(words) - 1] == "block\n"):
        continue
    else:
        final = final + line
print(final)
```

And the output I got was:

```
First sentence to keep.


Second sentence to keep.


Third sentence to keep.
```